# Autofilter with Array only returns one value

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this code that is basically a Frankenstein's monster of different code snippets that I've put together because I'm not that high on coding myself. It is an excel sheet that imports textfiles of xml-like code and I want it to show me the important stuff. In this case, I basically want the Autofilter to delete all rows that does not contain PA1*, PA2* and PA4*.

Earlier I only wanted to keep PA2* and PA4*, and I put them as two different Criteria, but it is my understanding and experience that it's not quite that easy when you want more than two criteria.

Running this code deletes all rows except for the ones with the last criteria of the three, in this case PA1*. I've tried wrapping my head around this but this summer heat makes a slow brain work even slower, appreciative of all help I can get!

*Snippet of code I am working with right now:*

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A200" & lastRow)


With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("<>PA4*", "<>PA2*", "<>PA1*")
    .Offset(0, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
 End With
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are numerous posts here addressing the two issues of an array of negated values, and wildcards, with autofilters.

Answer (score 1):

`Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A200" & lastRow)` would not return what you are expecting. Write `MsgBox(rng.Address)` on the line after to see the referred address.

Then change it to this:

`Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)`